# Is the difference in risk statistically significant?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, propensity-scores

I performed propensity score matching and thus generated a quasi-randomized study.

Now I got a risk for Akute Kidney Injury of

Drug1: 15.6 %
Drug 2: 11.2 %
Sample size = 4711 control + 4711 treated

I also tested for renal replacement therapy and got
Drug 1: 6.6 %
Drug 2: 6.2 %

and mortality 
Drug 1: 6.5 %
Drug 2: 6.3 %

Now intuitively, the risk difference in renal replacement and mortality is NOT statistically significant, but the risk for AKI is.

My question is this:  Which statistical test should I use to determine if the difference is statistically significant? Would a simple t.test suffice considering I calculated the risks using the mean()-function, but the risk is not "really" a mean on a ratio scale?